# Issue with a character substitution method by for-loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I´m trying to make a method that compares two strings and replaces the concurrent characters with asterisks for a beginner´s exercise.
I supose that already exists some methods to do that in String class or others, but the exercise doesn´t allows me to use them.
I tried to do it with a for-loop. Here´s my code:

```
public void substrings(){

    System.out.println ("Insert string 1 and press Intro");
    String string1 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Insert string 2 and press Intro");
    String string2 = sc.nextLine();

    String major;
    String minor;

    if (string1.length() >= string2.length()){
        major = string1;
        minor = string2;
    }
    else{
        major = string2;
        minor = string1;
    }

    char[]replace = new char[major.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < major.length(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < minor.length(); j++){
            if (major.charAt(i) != minor.charAt(j)){
                replace[i] = major.charAt(i);
            }
            else {
                replace[i] = '*';
            }
        }
        System.out.print (replace[i]);
    }
    System.out.print ("\n");
}
public static void main (String[]args){
    Substrings Test = new Substrings();
    Test.substrings();


}}
```

If I insert `five fingers` as string 1, and `five` as string 2, I obtain these:
`fiv* fing*rs`

while i was expecting some like `**** **ng*rs`

can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Much easier in Java 8: `string1.chars().mapToObj(e -> String.valueOf((char) (string2.chars().anyMatch(e2 -> e == e2) ? '*' : e) )).forEach(System.out::print);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never break out of your inner for-loop.  So your system.out.print(replace[I]) is always has the value when it's comparing e from five with the letter from 'five fingers'

So you'll want to break from your inner for-loop whenever you hit the else statement I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the loop after masking with an `*`

```
for (int i = 0; i < major.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < minor.length(); j++) {
        if (major.charAt(i) != minor.charAt(j)) {
            replace[i] = major.charAt(i);
        } else {
            replace[i] = '*';
            break; // here
        }
    }
    System.out.print(replace[i]);
}
System.out.print("\n");
```